# How to calculate likelihood of probit regression model conditioned on group membership?

Tags: logistic, anova, maximum-likelihood, probit

Consider a probit regression model with Bernoulli likelihood. Assuming there are $K$ groups, we assume, 
$$ \mathbb{E}[y_i|G_i = k] = \Phi(\theta_k)$$ where $\Phi(\cdot)$ is standard Gaussian CDF.

Now how can I calculate the likelihood function of $\theta_k$ assuming we observe the group $G_i$?

I am struggling to translate my understanding from general logistic regression to conditioned on multiple groups. Any hints?